# How to change angles in Pymol?

Tags: linux, bioinformatics, 3d-modelling, pymol

I use this

```
set_dihedral atom1_name, atom2_name, atom3_name, atom4_name, angle
```

for example

```
set_dihedral 22/C, 23/C, 26/C, 27/C, 130
```

So I want to change dihedral bonds this atoms

[image]

But when I wrote:

```
set_dihedral 23/CA, 23/C, 24/N, 24/CH3, 130
```

I had

```
SetDihedral-Error: Selection 1 doesn't contain a single atom/vertex.
SetDihedral-Error: Selection 2 doesn't contain a single atom/vertex.
SetDihedral-Error: Selection 3 doesn't contain a single atom/vertex.
SetDihedral-Error: Selection 4 doesn't contain a single atom/vertex.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, your 3D file doesn't contain **more than one structure** with the same names of the atoms you select? You could post your .cif file here. Or maybe you have to use a different selection syntax (e.g. "name" C23, etc. *see below*).

If I use the structure of [stearic acid](http://dx.doi.org/10.5517/ccsslgl) for example, this works flawlessly:

```
set_dihedral name c1,name c2,name c3,name c4, 130
```

[enter dihedral angle in PyMOL with a selection of four atoms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxPuK.png)

Comment: Thank you so much. I maybe use old comand from maybe old version of gromacs, because this set_dihedral 23/CA, 23/C, 24/N, 24/CH3, 130 - doesnt work

and this set_dihedral name C22,name C23,name C26,name C27, 130 work perfect. Thank you so much again.

Comment: You are very welcome. I have [this page](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Selection_Algebra) bookmarked because I always forget about the correct selection syntax :-)